# Почему регулярка берет лишние элементы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст :
`#Yandex #Apple Chainlink выпустил новую платформу для разработчиков #Functions, которая предоставляет бесплатный доступ к готовым функциям оракулов, упрощая процесс создания децентрализованных приложений на #Blockchain #Chainlink #девелопмент`

Есть регулярка : https://regex101.com/r/OsaFNu/1

Почему регулярка берет еще и **#Apple** , мне нужно чтоб брало только **#Functions**

См скрин:
[image]

Не могу добавить справа вот что : **слева** от искомого хештега ещё должно стоять: **пробел словоБезСимвола# пробел**

Comment: Справа от слова #Apple стоит пробел и слово Chainlink, в котором нету символа #, всё сходится. Почему вы решили, что регулярка не должна брать #Apple?

Comment: сорри, исправил. Слева должно стоять так: пробел словоБезСимвола# пробел

Comment: Ну, в показанной вами регулярке нет никаких условий для содержимого слева, поэтому #Apple и берётся

Comment: пробую вот так:
/(?!#[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]+\s+)(#[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)[,.!:?\s]?(\s[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я])/g

Но берет: "#Functions, к"    то есть почему-то захватывает запятую пробел и первую букву следующего слова (в данном случае букву "к") . Но опять же, как только запятую мне стоит убрать -> регулярка вообще ничего не захватывает . Хотя в регулярке прописано что один из знаков [,.!:?\s]? может быть а может и не быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно данное регулярное выражение вам поможет.
Перед и после слова с хэштегом не должно быть слова с хэштегом

`\b` - означает границу слова

`/(?<!#[a-zа-я0-9_]+\s+)(#\b[a-zа-я]+\b)(?!\s+#[a-zа-я0-9_]+)/gi`

Comment: какую роль `\b` играет в данном месте `#\b[a-zа-я]+` и чем это отличается от `#[a-zа-я]+`? Так же в некоторых языках стоит указывать ключ `u` unicode, что бы `\b` корректно работал с кириллицей

Comment: @ReDHooK ошибка https://imgur.com/a/q1OxDfw

Comment: @MikhailEliseev да, сайт regex101 выводит ошибку, но в коде у меня работает, поэтому проверьте в коде

Comment: спасибо и правда в JS интерп-ре всё работает как надо